# Create a finite-state machine

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning, automata

I need to create a finite-state machine which accepts strings whose characters are in {a,b,c} and produce output strings of T's and F's. The machine outputs a T once the characters ab is encountered and outputs F's before ab is encountered.

The inserted images are two possible state-machines I have come up with so far. I think both are acceptable.

Since the state-machine is to also output F's, should the F's also be accepting states?

Thanks for any feedback.

Tony

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

Comment: The 2nd machine outputs F on the string aab.

Comment: you should distinguish between what the machine prints at each step (T's and F's) and what language the machine accepts (which is what the accepting states are for). If your only interest is in the output, the accepting states are irrelevant. Your second machine prints F after aab, which seems wrong.

Comment: So I should only use the first state machine and I think, base on this feedback, that I don't need an accepting state in this case.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, you say I should "distinguish between what the machine prints at each step (T's and F's) and what language the machine accepts (which is what the accepting states are for)." I'm not quite sure what you mean. I designed the state-machine based on how my book designs them I am missing something from my diagram?

Comment: I didn't mean you need to distinguish between them in your diagram; I just meant you need to be aware of the conceptual difference between the two things.